# what is the difference between confidential and public client in OAuth2.0 specification?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I know that this question is bit naive. But I have been researching a lot on google, which can provide me the exact characteristics of public and confidential client types in OAuth2.0 standard. On what basis, it's decided that whether a client is confidential/public ?

1. Is "Login With Google" feature of StackOverflow, implies which type of client(public or credential) is StackOverflow ?
2. "Login With Google" in other android based mobile applications, implies which types of clients ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OAuth 2 for native application - what is difference between public and confidential client types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607025/oauth-2-for-native-application-what-is-difference-between-public-and-confident)